# Inserting select-case for different e-mail addresses

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I have code which save attachments with a click of a button.

Our freight-management team wants, depending on which e-mail address the customer e-mail with the attachment came from, to save in a customer specific folder. (Change `strFolderpath` depending on the case.)

I want to use the select-case method for easier changes and additions. I tried multiple alterations.

How do I add the select-case method for that use-case?

My working code:

```vb
Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Call the Namespace to see the sender e-mail address.
Set objNamespace = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = "C:\Folder\Test\"

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

    ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    ' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFiles = ""

    If lngCount > 0 Then

        ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName

            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            ' Delete the attachment.
            objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
            'check for html and use html tags in link
            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            'Use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
            'MsgBox strDeletedFiles

        Next i

        ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
        ' Check for HTML body
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
        Else
            objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
        End If
        objMsg.Save
    End If
Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Set objNamespace = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you having problems figuring out the address that the message was sent to? Or creating a case statement?

Comment: Creating a case statement tbh.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the `Select Case` to be within the `For Each objMsg` loop (incidentally you could also use an `If` statement if you're struggling with `Case` syntax).

```vba
For Each objMsg In objSelection
    Select Case True
        Case objMsg.SenderEmailAddress = "example@address.com"
            strFolderpath = "C:\Folder\sender1folder\"
        Case objMsg.SenderEmailAddress like "*domain.com"
            strFolderpath = "C:\Folder\otherfolder\"
        Case Else
            strFolderpath = "C:\Folder\Test\"
    End Select

    'rest of loop carry on here
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I did put it in inside my code and it seems to work, but it only uses the last case (case else) and it doesn't the e-mail addresses which I defined. Is something missing in the code which prevents the readout of the sender e-mail address?

Comment: That's a difficult one without knowing the exact data/code you're using. Best would be to use F8 to step through the code line-by-line until you come to where you know is going wrong, then check the variables (e.g. `debug.print objMsg.SenderEmailAddress` to see if anything's unexpected.

Comment: I debugged it and as result it shows me the ou "/O=EXCHANGELABS..." instead of the e-mail address. can you do something with that?

Comment: OK, try other properties than `.senderEmailAddress` - maybe base the filter on `.Sender`?

Comment: I found the solution. I tested with my internal mail-address instead of a external mail-address. With a external one, everything works like a charm. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it solved! please mark this answer as accepted so the question doesn't show as still open to other SO users.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the select-case method for that matter for easier changes and additions in the future, but i'm stuck right now

It is not necessary to use the select case operator. The very first thing you need to do is to get the sender's SMTP address in the code and only then you can decide which path is to use.

To get the SMTP address instead of Exchange one (X500) you can try to get an Exchange user using the [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser) method and then try to retrieve the [ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.primarysmtpaddress) property value.

Read more about that in the [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) article.

After you have retrieved the SMTP address you could analyze the content and choose the appropriate folder for saving attachments.